# Retrieve Modified Request URL from $_SERVER -php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

when browser request the below url

> `http://test.localhost/mobile.html?page=online&option=test&_ga=2.145898866.737559230.1531785796-1355088823.1529293502`

the htaccess file rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1
```

modifies the URL to

> `http://test.localhost/index.php?page=mobile`

In the index.php file have the below the echo statements.

```
echo "Request URI:" .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  . "<br/>";
echo "Query String:" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']  . "<br/>";
```

it display the below output

> Request URI:
>   `http://test.localhost/order-online/order.html?_ga=7.145874566.73777770.1531785796-135578823.152927502
>   Query String:page=mobile`

Request URI display the original request, **how do i get the rewritten Request URI `http://test.localhost/index.php?page=mobile`**

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking? Do you want that all requests become `http://test.localhost/index.php?page=mobile`? Or all requests which have a query string `page=online&option=test&_ga=2.145898866.737559230.1531785796-1355088823.1529293502` should become that URI? And, what does `orders.epicpizza.com.au` have to do with anything?

Comment: want to echo the rewritten htaccess url   http://test.localhost/index.php?page=mobile  is there any $_SERVER parameter exists to display the rewritten url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your PHP code you can use this code to get rewritten URI:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```